# Visual Basic Time Difference

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I have a program that has to calculate the cost of a skateboard per hour. The user is supposed to pick the rent time and the return time. SO! I made a function.

```
Private Function ElapsedTime(ByVal dtmEarly As DateTime, ByVal dtmLate As DateTime) As Integer
    Dim timeDiff As TimeSpan = dtmLate - dtmEarly
    Return Math.Abs(timeDiff.Hours)
End Function
```

So I pick 10:00:00 PM for rent time and 12:00:00 AM for return time, JUST 2 HOURS AHEAD!

so my timeDiff.Hours returns -=22 at the end.

Can anyone help me? It's only there where I have a problem. Thank You!

Comment: Tell us the full value of `dtmEarly` and `dtmLate` (which are **terrible** variable names by the way).  My guess is that you are passing in the same day.  And 12AM is 22 hours less than 10PM on the same day.

Comment: I just saw this....

dtmEarly: #2/27/2015 11:15:52 PM#
dtmLate:  #2/27/2015 1:15:52 AM#

Why is it not changing the day after? How do I make them both work together?

Comment: Hmm, you already discovered this problem by yourself.  That's why you chose to use Math.Abs().  That didn't help :)  You can use DateTime.TimeOfDay but you'd better close shop at nightfall.  Fix the real problem instead.

Comment: In order to help you, we need to know where do the parameter values come from... datetime pickers?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this type of problem for another one some days ago, which can give you a way to solve your problem. Here I used MaskedTextBox, you can also use DateTimePicker control.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim stTime() As String
        Dim endTime() As String

        stTime = Split(MaskedTextBox1.Text, ":")
        endTime = Split(MaskedTextBox2.Text, ":")


        Dim startTime As TimeSpan = New TimeSpan(Val(stTime(0)), Val(stTime(1)), Val(stTime(2)))
        Dim PresentTime As TimeSpan = New TimeSpan(Val(endTime(0)), Val(endTime(1)), Val(endTime(2)))


        Dim difTime As TimeSpan = PresentTime - startTime

        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("You are already {0}hour(s) {1}minute(s) {2}second(s) late.", difTime.Hours, difTime.Minutes, difTime.Seconds))

    End Sub
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: This is still not working. It's not changing the day, it stays on 2/27/2015 for both dates. It's not incrementing to the 28th

Comment: MaskedTextBoxes used to show only the times. Their Mask Property was **"00:00:00"**. So they are not ready to response for dates.

Comment: No I know, I changed mine to DateTimePicker

Answer (score 0):

What I'll do and seems to be working is, I'll add a custom format so it lets the user pick the day that they want to return the board. Thanks for the help anyways guys!